# REMOVE padding on span element

Tags: html, css, padding

This could possibly be the easiest problem to solve, but I am tearing my hair out. I have seen many posts about adding padding to spans and adding padding to either side of multi-line text...

I am looking for the exact opposite. I want to REMOVE all padding from the span and have the background-color sit right on the text, so no padding all round.

I have literally played with everything possible ...margins, padding, line-heights, floats..nothing is taking away the padding!

### This is what it looks like in safari:

[image: This is what it looks like in safari]

### Looks even worse in IE:

[image: Looks even worse in IE]

I've had to increase the line-height way more than I want otherwise IE cuts the text off.

Is there anyone out there with a possible solution before I throw my mac out the window?

```css
.headerBlock {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.headerSpan {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 1px;
  font-size: 55px;
  line-height: 60px;
  /*display: inline;*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Cervo Thin';
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="headerBlock">
  <span class="headerSpan">We're a small freelance design studio based in Surrey. We love being involved in projects that challenge our imagination and keep our creative cogs in stellar condition. If you’re itching to inject some creative genius into your projects, <a class="yellowBg" style="color: #000;" href="#">give us a shout!</a></span>
 </h3>
```

Comment: please share your code that is causing this problem. otherwise we can't help you

Comment: try `display: inline-block` with `padding:0` before throwing it out.

Comment: Please share your html and css

Comment: @caramba fiddle is not required and not recommended. External links can be changed or gone ' dead ' after some time. The user should include his code in a Stackoverflow snippet. Here. On this site.

Comment: inline-block causes the background-color to be a block as opposed to follow the flow of the text!

Comment: Did you try setting `line-height` and `font-size` to the same px amount?

Comment: Another thing you can try is using the `<mark></mark>` tag in html

Comment: The problem seems to be that you need the element in question to *behave like an inline element* but you want it to *display like an inline-block element*. You see reducing `line-height` will work on `inline-block` elements, but `inline-block` elements wont wrap the `background-color` with the *length of the text*, instead it'll occupy the width of the screen since, in this case, the text stretches the width of the screen. Are you open to exploring alternative methods? And how dynamic is this text, that is to say, will it need to change often?

Comment: I am open to ANY suggestions, the text won't change often at all, it literally sits on my home page and another one on my about page. http://www.wearestellar.co.uk. i have tried setting the line-height to the same as the font-size...originally the line-height was less than 60px but when my friend sent me a screenshto on IE it was literally cutting the text in half